# Execute Javascript in Test Cafe

Tags: javascript, testing, dom, automated-tests, testcafe

I'm totally new to Javascript and executing this kind of queries in the console browser.
When I execute this code in the Chrome console  I have an answser what my code should do next.

```
        if (scjs.getResponses()[385] && 
            scjs.getResponses()[385].bids &&
            scjs.getResponses()[385].bids.length === 1) {
            console.log('true')
        } else {
            console.log('false')
        }
```

And it always works in the console. 
My question is: how can I use the same code in Testcafe to create an assertion?

Thank you

Comment: It looks this is one of your first posts here so welcome. Can you provide an example implementation (even if it has errors or the test fails) using testcafe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you. I know this answer but it didn't work.
Finaly I found the solution:

```
    const getVisibility = ClientFunction((format) => {

        let result;

        if ((window as any).scjs.getResponses()[format] && 
        (window as any).scjs.getResponses()[format].bids &&
        (window as any).scjs.getResponses()[format].bids.length === 1) {

        result = true

        } else {
        result = false
        }
        return result;          
    });

    const isVisible = await getVisibility(format);
    return isVisible;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ClientFunction` approach for this purpose. Refer the [Obtain Client-Side Info](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/obtain-client-side-info.html) TestCafe documentation topic for details.